# How to access Folder/Subfolders/Files using nested loops for file conversions?

Tags: command-line, bash, video, ffmpeg

In a structure like this:

```
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/xml tutorials/Main/video1.mp4
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/xml tutorials/Main/video2.mp4
....
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/java tutorials/Main/video1.mp4
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/java tutorials/Main/video2.mp4
....
```

I need to convert the videos and save the new files like this:

```
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/xml tutorials/Converted/video1.mp4
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/xml tutorials/Converted/video2.mp4
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/java tutorials/Converted/video1.mp4
/home/me/Videos/Downloads/Videos/java tutorials/Converted/video2.mp4
```

I want to convert these videos using `ffmpeg` by running a nested loop through the `Folder/Subfolders/Videos`.

By running this I can loop through all files in the current directory:

```
for f in *; do ffmpeg -i "$f" ... ; done
```

How can I use nested loops for this, so that bash itself can automatically browse `Videos/xml tutorials/main/` and do the conversion, put them in `Videos/xml tutorials/converted`, and itself move to `Videos/java tutorials/main/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, most probably there is a more efficient/optimised way to do it, but for now whatever works. But ffmpeg didn't take spaces in names so had to rename all of them by replacing space with underscore.

In Videos folder which has the different tutorials, running this works -

```
for f in * ; do
  for g in "$f"/Main/* ; do
     ffmpeg -i "$g" -s 854x480 -c:v libx265 "$f"/Converted/$(basename $g)
  done
done
```

Here, `$f` gets the names of the folders, and then `$g` gets the names of the files themselves, along with their paths and extensions.